# Why is this votes/posts ratio always 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dataexplorer

I'm working with SEDE to create a graph of the ratio of votes to posts. Having eliminated all the actual errors, I'm faced with a new problem: for some reason, the ratio is *always* 1. This is the current SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(p.CreationDate AS DATE) AS [CreationDate],
       COUNT(CAST(v.CreationDate AS DATE)) / COUNT(CAST(p.CreationDate AS DATE))
         AS [Ratio]
FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN Votes v ON v.PostId = p.Id
WHERE v.VoteTypeId = ##VoteType:int?2## AND
      p.PostTypeId = 1 OR p.PostTypeId = 2
GROUP BY CAST(p.CreationDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY Ratio
```

The query itself can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/opensource/query/edit/335928#graph).

It was [suggested in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22738751#22738751) that this might be because joining the tables results in every possible combination, so the number of votes and posts is always the same (thus `n/n = 1`). Is this correct, and if so what should I be doing instead?

Comment: Bacause your count is grouped on p.CreationDate

Comment: @JoeTaras ...so what *should* I be grouping on?

Comment: What do you get when you select the two sets independently filtered?  Do this for a few example postID values and it should be very clear why your `JOIN` isn't working as expected.

Comment: @HartCO I don't get you. What do you mean by independently filtering them with some postID values?

Comment: You're grouping on CreationDate and your count is a count of CreationDate -- there's only one unique CreationDate per group, because that's what DEFINES the group. If you want votes per post, use the join you have, group on p.Id, and select count(v.VoteId). If you care about creation date, join back to the Post table p2 by p.Id and select p2.CreationDate

Comment: @EdPlunkett But surely `count(p.Id) ≡ 1` no matter what? How does that help?

Comment: @ArtOfCode -- Very true, my bad, I mistyped! You want `count(v.Id)` instead -- I fixed my comment and did it that way in my answer

Comment: @EdPlunkett It's not `COUNT(DISTINCT))` it doesn't matter which field from `v` is in the `COUNT()` unless that field is sometimes `NULL` and another isn't.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm saying, without a `JOIN` or aggregation, just run two `SELECT *` queries filtered with the appropriate `WHERE` criteria, so that you can see how the relationship between the two tables works out.  If that doesn't help you see it, it's at least a better set of sample data to post in your question for others to help.

Comment: I didn't realize you had a full set of data in that link to data explorer, that's handy, still narrowing down to a bite size chunk is helpful in understanding problems with aggregations.  Looks like you've got an answer that is helpful if not exactly what you're after from dasblinkenlight

Comment: Just deleted my answer. I don't have a clue. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both sides of an in an inner join exist, both `COUNT(CAST(v.CreationDate AS DATE))` and `COUNT(CAST(p.CreationDate AS DATE))`will return exactly the same number, which is the number of rows in a group<sup>*</sup>.

If you would like to count how many new votes per new post you've got on a given date, use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT CAST(p.CreationDate AS DATE) AS [CreationDate],
       COUNT(DISTINCT v.Id) / COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS [Ratio]
FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN Votes v ON v.PostId = p.Id
WHERE v.VoteTypeId = ##VoteType:int?2## AND
      p.PostTypeId = 1 OR p.PostTypeId = 2
GROUP BY CAST(p.CreationDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY Ratio
```

<sup>*</sup> assuming that `CreationDate` is not nullable.